# MacOS Big Sur not setting the COLUMNS environmental variable

Tags: terminal, macos-big-sur

I was having trouble using the shell vi editing mode - the cursor would move back a line sometimes. I finally tracked it down - Terminal is no longer setting COLUMNS, so the shell defaulted to 80.

I had a comment in my .profile that COLUMNS use to be set by TERMINAL, but now it isn't. I can't find anything in the Preferences that would appear to enable that.

Anyone know what happened, and how one might fix it. The original idea was users would resize windows, and pass the new size down to the shell so editing would work properly.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67536043/why-does-kshs-vi-mode-in-terminal-on-macos-big-sur-sometimes-corrupts-the-edi (yes, I know that's yours too!)

Answer (score 0):

```sh
export COLUMNS=<number>
```

in your .bashrc.

Comment: You completely misunderstood the issue. Sure that works initially. Now resize the window. Duh, COLUMNS never changes.