# ksh's vi-mode sometimes corrupts the edit line - new version on GitHub fixes it

Tags: macos, terminal, ksh

ORIGINAL ISSUE:

I noticed that sometimes when trying to edit a line in the history to re-run a command, that ksh would garble the line and move the cursor up a line. It was really bizarre.

- first found that it was only long lines where the problem occurred
- debugging, found that the `COLUMNS` variable was unset (pretty sure `Terminal` use to set it)

I could set it by hand to some big number, but then other problems appeared.

I cannot find any way to force Terminal to update the `COLUMNS` value as the window resizes - how can I do this?

EDIT: April 2023
Ventura broke my fix so window resize still making it difficult to edit command line.

Base on an answer below from Trey Valenta, I found that [Martijn Dekker](https://social.cybre.town/@mcdutchie) is supporting the abandoned ATT source, and has had 4 releases to date; [tap here for the link](https://github.com/ksh93/ksh/releases).

Unlike the ATT build system, this thing is really easy to use:

- download the src as a zip file
- unzip it
- open the README.md with a Markdown reader
- follow instructions, which for me was:

  - sh bin/package make
  - sh bin/package test # unnecessary, I did it out of curiosity
  - bin/package install /usr/local
  - edit Terminal prefs so it launches ksh from /usr/local/bin

Make sure you edit your profile, .kshrc, etc to insure no old links to /bin/ksh

Comment: Is there any particular reason why you are still using ksh, vs bash/zsh ... ?

Comment: @Philippe Two. Korn wrote a detailed book on all facets of his shell, and I still reference it for various reasons. Second, I started using it at Bell Labs shortly after it went live, and actually had the opportunity to interact with him. I’ve used it on Macs for 20 years now, no reason to switch. If I were to switch, I’d probably try a new shell like Fish.

Comment: Still seems to be an issue on Ventura (with `Version AJM 93u+ 2012-08-01`).

Comment: @jhfrontz agreed - but building the app from source as others have done is a huge hurtle. I can’t find a place the offers M binaries…

Comment: @jhfrontz Got the supported source and its trivial to build and install! Working fine now!

Answer (score 3):

I just got a new 14" MacBook with the M1 chip and Monterey, and hit the same issue. It doesn't happen on my 2015 MacBook Pro with MacOS 12.4 beta, and after some research I discovered I can get Korn Shell to update the variables on SIGWINCH if I run the binary in x64_64 mode via `arch -x86_64 /bin/ksh`.

I tried setting a trap on `WINCH` (window change) that will set the COLUMNS and LINES variables, but while I'm resizing my iTerm window, multiple WINCH signals are sent and the`PS1` prompt will be printed each time.

Why it works under x86_64 but not arm64 is beyond me.

I *could* use this as an excuse to switch to zsh, but my `.kshrc` file has roots dating back to 1991 and there are enough differences in how command-line editing works that it throws my muscle-memory for a loop.

Comment: Thanks for your solution. Like you, my kshrc file goes back even further, and since my shell use is limited now it’s just not worth switching.

Comment: It _does_ seem like `SIGWINCH` isn't getting sent to the shell.  Interestingly enough, when I `ssh` to another (x86_64) system, I have no problems.  So perhaps the arm64 executable is not allowed to receive that signal (is SIP that granular)?

Comment: @jhfrontz ksh is surely in basic maintenance mode now, assume David Korn is no longer involved. I’d guess that some OS change broke it but the newer way to stay in sync was not adopted. I’m close to the end of my career so no incentive to switch to something else. Also I occasionally write complex scripts, and having a printed reference is a real benefit to ksh.

Comment: @DavidH the thing is, this is the same binary -- `arch` just selects which part to "run".  So presumably Xcode is compiling the same source to two different architectures (and somehow the ARM binary execution is treated differently).

Comment: I ended up building from https://github.com/ksh93/ksh IIRC, it's using slightly different code to handle SIGWINCH and works on arm64, and doesn't cause me as much grief. I did re-attempt switching to zsh, but the command-line editor gave me grief when I tried to have it emulate vi mode in ksh.

Comment: I wonder if it's the code difference or if it's the runtime loader doing something different with the ARM "side" of the stock universal binary.

Comment: @TreyValenta I just got the source and built it - the window resize now working and latest from 2022 has 1000 issues fixed too! The system ksh is 10 years old now!

Answer (score 1):

My suspicion is that the ARM portion of the universal binary is being treated/executed differently by the MacOS runtime loader (and not properly propagating `SIGWINCH` to the running code).

Riffing on @trey-valenta's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71963006/318902) detailing a workaround, I added this to the bottom of my `$HOME/.profile`:

```
# workaround for defective arm64 binary on MacOS
[ "$(uname -m)" == arm64 ] && test -x $(whence arch) && file ${SHELL} | grep -q x86_64 && exec arch -x86_64 ${SHELL}
```

I contemplated using [`lipo`](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/429199/10389) but opted for `file` in the name of portability (I typically use the same `.profile` across architectures/OSs).

Comment: But this means you are using Rosetta to run the shell, no? Trey Volenta posted a GitHub link in a comment on another post to a link where you can get a supported version of ksh that doesn't have the issue.

Comment: @DavidH yes, it's running the x86_64 contents via Rosetta 2.  The potential minor performance hit is worth it to me to continue to use the stock shell.

Answer (score 1):

Based on [Dave's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67536044/4618482) I was able to find another solution that works for me with the stock `ksh`, but it's not very pretty. Create `~/.kshrc` as follows:

```bash
trap 'COLUMNS=$(tput cols); LINES=$(tput lines)' WINCH
COLUMNS=$(tput cols)
LINES=$(tput lines)
```

This sets the correct values at startup and after every window change.

When the window is resized `ksh` prints `$PS1` on every `WINCH` signal. This isn't very pretty, but it has no lasting effect and I resize windows rarely, so I'm happy with this solution that lets me use the stock `ksh` binary.

PS: It's also possible to use another file than `~/.kshrc` and set `ENV` to the filename in `.profile`.

Answer (score 0):

This took me forever to track down and fix. ksh will run an `.env` file before it runs any command, so that's the hook where you can set the value, assuming you can find the value.

After searching high and low, I found that `stty` will output the current rows and columns, but the values are buried in a big payload of other info. Then I tripped on the `resize` option, that just outputs the rows and columns as two numbers.

By filtering the output, one can get just the columns number. The solution is to thus add this in a .env file, and make sure `ENV` is set in your .profile.

```
COLUMNS=$(stty size | sed -e 's/[0-9]* \([0-9]\)/\1/')
```

Comment: would `COLUMNS=$(tput cols)` be simpler/faster?

Comment: @user7761803 I missed your comment earlier. I will try this soon.

Comment: I should have updated this - it doesn't work, as the value from `tput` doesn't get updated when you resize the screen :(

Comment: @user7761803 I believe I had tried that earlier.

Comment: But this (setting COLUMNS in .env) doesn't help when you resize, does it?

Comment: @jhfrontz I don’t understand your question. Of course it works if you drag to resize the Terminal window - that’s the reason for this answer! Been working great for over a year!

Comment: I'm confused -- how do you get your .env to be run on WINCH?

Comment: Or is it that .env is executed prior to reacting to the CLI line-editing?

Comment: @jhfrontz read the first line of my answer - .env is run before every command is executed. Run a command, COLUMNS=80, expand window, nothing happens, run a command, .env runs, COLUMNS=120.

Comment: Right, ok— so expand a window, try to scroll through history, still have problem.

Comment: I have `ENV=$HOME/.shrc`, but it isn't executed before every command – only at startup of an interactive shell.